# Second Set of Coords Displaying (1, None)

Tags: python, function, opencv, mouseevent

I am using a depth camera that uses the mouse to click on points on an image that has already been taken. I want to be able to click on two points in the image and connect a line between the two while displaying the distance. I already figured out how to use cv2.line() and cv2.putText() to do this.

The issue that I am having is that my program is returning the second set of coordinates as (1, None). I am not sure why it is doing this, I have attached my code below.

```py
def click_event(event, x, y, x2, y2):
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        print(x, ' ', y)
        print(x2, ' ', y2)
        point1 = (x,y)
        point2 = (x2,y2)
        font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
     
        cv2.putText(img, str(x) + ',' + str(y), (x,y), font, 1, (255, 0, 0), 2)
        cv2.putText(img, str(x2) + ',' + str(y2), (x2,y2), font, 1, (255, 0, 0), 2)
        cv2.line(img, point1, point2, (0,255,0), thickness=3, lineType=4)
        cv2.imshow('window', img)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    img = cv2.imread('imageTwo.png', 1)
    cv2.imshow('window', img)
    cv2.setMouseCallback('window', click_event)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: x,y are the mouse coords. but x2,y2 ? they are not properly defined (and should not be part of the callback signature, that's wrong !). what's your plan about those ?

Comment: I see, thank you. And I am not sure. I only needed x2, y2 to be the ending points to draw the line. Is there a way to do this with only one set of coords?

Comment: are those the **previously** clicked point coords ?

Comment: yes (x,y) represent when you first click on the image which is the starting point of the line and (x2, y2) represents when you click on the image again and is the ending point of the line

Comment: this is not the proper signature of a mouse callback. you can't just wish this to be different. if you need previous mouse positions, you need to store them somewhere. please consult official docs.

Comment: I am new to python and programming. Should I save the first set of coords into point1 and then when the user clicks again, check if the first set of coords has been saved and then continue with the function?